# Lowest common ancestor Cracking coding Interview Solution

Tags: algorithm, lowest-common-ancestor

I am trying to understand one of the solutions in Cracking the Coding Interview page 129. This is about finding the lowest common ancestor. Please see code below. My questions are in the comments

In summary, my questions are:

1) For this line of code:

```
 if(root.left == p || root.left == q) return root.left;
```

**Why return root.left and not root?**

2) For these lines of code:

```
else if (nodesFromLeft == ONE_NODE_FOUND) {
     if (root == p) return p;  
     else if (root == q) return q; 
     }
```

**Why return p if root==p, how is this the ancestor? Likewise for q.**

Here is the entire code below:

```
 static int TWO_NODES_FOUND = 2;
 static int ONE_NODE_FOUND = 1;
 static int NO_NODES_FOUND = 0;

 // Checks how many “special” nodes are located under this root
 int covers(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {

      int ret = NO_NODES_FOUND;
      if (root == null) return ret;
      if (root == p || root == q) ret += 1;
      ret += covers(root.left, p, q);
      if(ret == TWO_NODES_FOUND) // Found p and q
           return ret;
 return ret + covers(root.right, p, q);
 }

 TreeNode commonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
      if (q == p && (root.left == q || root.right == q)) return root;

      int nodesFromLeft = covers(root.left, p, q); // Check left side
      if (nodesFromLeft == TWO_NODES_FOUND) {
           if(root.left == p || root.left == q) return root.left;//Qn1:See above
      else return commonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
      } 
      else if (nodesFromLeft == ONE_NODE_FOUND) {
           if (root == p) return p; //Qn 2: See qn above
           else if (root == q) return q; //Qn2: See qn above
      }
      int nodesFromRight = covers(root.right, p, q); // Check right side
      if(nodesFromRight == TWO_NODES_FOUND) {
           if(root.right == p || root.right == q) return root.right;
      else return commonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
      }
      else if (nodesFromRight == ONE_NODE_FOUND) {
           if (root == p) return p;
           else if (root == q) return q;
      }
      if (nodesFromLeft == ONE_NODE_FOUND && nodesFromRight == ONE_NODE_FOUND) return root;

      else return null;
 }
```

Comment: `My questions are in the comments`: Don't put them in code, put your question explicitly to make clear what you are asking.

Comment: ok, sorry about that. have improved the code and put questions in bold outside of the code with comment in the code at lines I am unclear about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why return root.left and not root?

When `nodesFromLeft` is 2, then both `p` and `q` are under `root.left`.
If one of them is `root.left` then that's the common ancestor. One is `root.left`
and the other is below it.

> Why return p if root==p, how is this the ancestor?

When `nodesFromLeft` is 1, then one node is under `root.left` and the other is
either `root`, under `root.right`, or it doesn't exist in the tree. If it's `root`,
then that's the ancestor. One not is `root` and the other is below it on the left.

The case where it's under `root.right` or not in the tree is checked on the last two lines.

Comment: when you say 'if one of them is root.left, then that's the common ancestor', I differ in my current understanding because if one of them is root.left, and the other is below it, should it not be 'root' that's the common ancestor?

Comment: @stretchr A node can have itself as an ancestor so we don't need to go a level up. The first paragraph at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor describes this scenario: "if v has a direct connection from w, w is the lowest common ancestor"

Comment: i see, got it. Didn't know a node can have itself as an ancestor. That clarifies alot, thanks!